# xsd file : unable to have a sequence of elements with the same name

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to export an Excel file into XML which looks like this:

```
<Data form="DTA_CAL">
  <Item>
    <Dim prop="SII_TAX_COL">010</Dim>
    <Dim prop="SII_TAX_DEC">1010.15</Dim>
    <Dim prop="SII_TAX_RUB">010</Dim>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Dim prop="SII_TAX_COL">010</Dim>
    <Dim prop="SII_TAX_DEC">2010</Dim>
    <Dim prop="SII_TAX_RUB">020</Dim>
  </Item>
</Data>
```

But I'm not able to have a correct xsd which allow to have a sequence of element with the same name, I tried this :

```
<xs:element name="Data">

       <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="Item"  maxOccurs="3">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:all>
                                    <xs:element name="Dim" >
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                         <xs:attribute name="prop" type="xs:string" fixed="SII_TAX_COL">
                                                         </xs:attribute>
                                                    </xs:extension> 
                                                </xs:simpleContent> 
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="Dim">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                         <xs:attribute name="prop" type="xs:string" fixed="SII_TAX_DEC">
                                                         </xs:attribute>
                                                    </xs:extension> 
                                                </xs:simpleContent> 
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="Dim">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                         <xs:attribute name="prop" type="xs:string" fixed="SII_TAX_RUB" >
                                                         </xs:attribute>
                                                    </xs:extension> 
                                                </xs:simpleContent> 
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>                                                               
                                </xs:all>
                            </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But got errors when I upload this XSD file, I cannot have same name 'Dim' in 3 elements inside a sequence.

How can I have the XSD to describe this XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can not define three elements with the same name. You can define only one element and restrict its occurrence with `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`. And you can restrict the attribute values to be a sequence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Dim" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="prop" use="required">
                                                <xs:simpleType>
                                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="SII_TAX_COL"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="SII_TAX_DEC"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="SII_TAX_RUB"/>
                                                    </xs:restriction>
                                                </xs:simpleType>
                                            </xs:attribute>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="form" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="DTA_CAL"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But the above will not guarantee that the attribute values are unique. If you want them to be unique, you have to add a unique constraint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Dim" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="prop" use="required">
                                                <xs:simpleType>
                                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="SII_TAX_COL"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="SII_TAX_DEC"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="SII_TAX_RUB"/>
                                                    </xs:restriction>
                                                </xs:simpleType>
                                            </xs:attribute>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="Dim_prop">
                        <xs:selector xpath="Dim"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@prop"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="form" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="DTA_CAL"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The handling would be easier, if you organize your XML in this way:

```
<Data form="DTA_CAL">
  <Item>
    <Dim SII_TAX_COL="010" SII_TAX_DEC="1010.15" SII_TAX_RUB="010"/>
  </Item>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule is that if sibling elements have the same name, then they must have the same type.

XSD isn't really based on the philosophy that you should be able to design your XML any way you like, and then write a description of that design in XSD. Rather, the idea is that XSD supports a set of (what someone considers to be) good design practices in XML.

However, XSD 1.1 allows you to define pretty well any constraints you like using XPath assertions.

And don't forget there is always the transform-then-validate option: perform an XSLT transformation on the XML (e.g. in your case renaming the elements Dim1, Dim2, and Dim3), then validate the result.